# Can we change the SSL certificate delivered by Avast Web/Mail Shield Self-signed Root for IMAP mail client of Kolab 16 server?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, pki, kolab

A pop-up window shows a warning message about a self signed certificate at every start of Outlook on a PC and on Samsung mail at the initial configuration.

[Warning about the SSL certificate in Outlook 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0ujD.png)

Where is this certificate stored (Kolab 16 running on Ubuntu 18.04)? And how can I create new one?

[image: Avast Web-Mail Shield self-signed Root certificate english]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Could you please provide screenshots in english or if not possible translate them. Also please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is a transtation of the images captures in english.

Answer (score 0):

This certificate is delivered by the Avast antivirus installed on a workstation. This certificate is stored in the workstation, not on the Kolab server.

To change the certificate associated to the warning about the SSL certificate in Outlook, you have to modify /etc/guam/sys.config and restart guam on the Kolab server :

1) At the line 29/79 of the file, you change the file path and the name of the certificate assiciated to the desired file.

2) At the line 46/79 of the file, you change the file path and the name of the certificate  assiciated to the desired file.

3) And for a plus, you can modify the port 9993 at the line 10/79 for the port number 993 witch will correct a bug in the default file.

4) Restart the guam service by typing : service guam restart

- The original certificate file /etc/ssl/kolab.installation.lan/cyrus-imapd.pem concactenates a certificate and a private key. So you can do the same with a command like :
  cat fullchain.pem privkey.pem > crtprivkey.pem